# Detele files depending of date in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to remove all files that are from 2014 with the extension of .png, excluding the folders with Powershell.

**This is as far as I got:**

```
Remove-Item X:\path\* -include .png -recurse
```

How do I get the date of the files so I can delete only the .png files that are from 2014?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.png | 
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -match '2014'} | 
% {"Deleting $($_.FullName)"; Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

Add the `-Force` after the `Remove-Item` if you don't want it to ask you before deletion of each file

Comment: Nice. Is there any way of output which file that it deletes? So that I can follow the progress in the command prompt?

Comment: Get-ChildItem X:\path -Recurse -Filter *.png | 
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -match '2014'} | Foreach-Object { Write-Host "Deleting $($_)";
Remove-Item $_;}

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!